# How can I setup multiple Django Apps using Supervisor (including Gunicorn and Nginx)? bind() to [::]:8090 failed (98: Address already in use)

Tags: django, linux, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

I already deployed a Django/Wagtail App using Supervisor, Gunicorn and Nginx (on Debian Buster), so I can reach it with http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8090.

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/cms

server {
    server_name xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    listen 8090;
    listen [::]:8090 ipv6only=on;
    error_log /home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/var/log/gunicorn-error.log;
    access_log /home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/var/log/gunicorn-access.log;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/www.mysite.com/www/my-site/cms/admin_panel;
    }
        location /media/ {
        root /home/www.mysite.com/www/my-site/cms/admin_panel;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

```
/etc/supervisor/conf.d/guni-mysite-admin.conf

[program:guni-mysite-admin]
command=/home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/bin/gunicorn admin_panel.wsgi:application --config /home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/etc/gunicorn/conf.py
user=www.mysite.com
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

```
/etc/supervisor/conf.d/nginx-mysite-admin.conf

[program:nginx-mysite-admin]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/var/log/nginx-error.log
stdout_logfile=/home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/var/log/nginx-access.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=2MB
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=2MB
```

```
/home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/etc/gunicorn/conf.py

workers = 3
keepalive = 5
user = 'www.mysite.com'
proc_name = 'admin_panel'
loglevel = 'error'
errorlog = '/home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/var/log/gunicorn-error.log'
accesslog = '/home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/var/log/gunicorn-access.log'
bind = 'unix:/home/www.mysite.com/.local/share/virtualenvs/cms-WqsZ9qOt/run/gunicorn.sock'
raw_env = ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=admin_panel.settings.production']
pythonpath = '/home/www.mysite.com/www/mysite/cms/admin_panel'
```

Now I added 2 more Django Apps the same way. Unfortunately Supervisor can´t bring them up. Sometimes 1 out of 3 runs, but most of the time none of them work. In case it works it creates 3 processes (idk if that´s how it is supposed to be).

```
$ sudo lsof -i:8090

COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   3631     root   16u  IPv4 961301189      0t0  TCP *:8090 (LISTEN)
nginx   3631     root   17u  IPv6 961301190      0t0  TCP *:8090 (LISTEN)
nginx   3632 www-data   16u  IPv4 961301189      0t0  TCP *:8090 (LISTEN)
nginx   3632 www-data   17u  IPv6 961301190      0t0  TCP *:8090 (LISTEN)
nginx   3633 www-data   16u  IPv4 961301189      0t0  TCP *:8090 (LISTEN)
nginx   3633 www-data   17u  IPv6 961301190      0t0  TCP *:8090 (LISTEN)
```

Nginx error log gives *98: Address already in use*, even on port 81 (took it as default port because Apache is using 80), which is not used. Apache should not be the problem, because it doesn´t work, even when Apache is turned off.

```
/var/log/nginx/error.log

...
2021/08/06 12:41:54 [emerg] 24927#24927: bind() to [::]:4020 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/08/06 12:41:54 [emerg] 24927#24927: bind() to [::]:8090 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/08/06 12:41:54 [emerg] 24927#24927: bind() to [::]:81 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/08/06 12:41:54 [emerg] 24927#24927: bind() to [::]:8070 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/08/06 12:41:54 [emerg] 24927#24927: bind() to [::]:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/08/06 12:41:54 [emerg] 24927#24927: bind() to [::]:4030 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/08/06 12:41:54 [emerg] 24928#24928: still could not bind()
...
```

### Output - $ sudo service nginx status

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-08-07 10:27:49 CEST; 50s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 25364 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 25366 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 25367 (nginx)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 4.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─25367 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
           ├─25368 nginx: worker process
           └─25369 nginx: worker process

Aug 07 10:27:49 xxxxxxx.server.linevast.org systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Aug 07 10:27:49 xxxxxxx.server.linevast.org systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to parse PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Aug 07 10:27:49 xxxxxxx.server.linevast.org systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

### Output - $ sudo supervisorctl status all

Gunicorn processes are running fine, Ngnix processes try to start, but break. Nginx Error Log gives *bind() to [::]:8090 failed (98: Address already in use)*

```
guni-csd-admin                   RUNNING   pid 25564, uptime 0:06:44
guni-csd-phrases                 RUNNING   pid 25567, uptime 0:06:44
guni-kc-admin                    RUNNING   pid 25566, uptime 0:06:44
nginx-csd-admin                  STARTING
nginx-csd-phrases                RUNNING   pid 31118, uptime 0:00:01
nginx-kc-admin                   RUNNING   pid 31103, uptime 0:00:02
```

Comment: It looks like you try to start nginx via supervisor but there is an inastance that is running already (managed by systemd or init).

Comment: Indeed it does look like there´s already something running. That´s why I stopped Nginx and Supervisor, so the needed ports are definitely not used. `sudo lsof -i:8070`for example has no output. It looks like Supervisor or Nginx blocks itself for some reason.

Comment: Try "sudo service nginx status" and see what it says.

Comment: Sure I added it to the question.

Comment: As you can see in the output there is a running instance of nginx loaded by systemd. To avoid conflict you should pick one method to start and manage nginx daemon either systemd or supervisor. In my opinion it is better to use default method (systemd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

With following setup I successfully run two clients, three API´s, a Wordpress and Php Analytics Site without conflicts: As an example one of the API´s has Apache2 HTTP Server as Proxy (listening to port 80) which is forwarding to Nginx (not controlled by Supervisor which actually is the solution!) Gunicorn is conntrolled by Supervisor. So I just quit using Supervisor for Nginx processes. It may would work without using ipv6only, but I want to use it for sake of better control over IP bindings. So I´m fine with this.